# Push notifications from RSS in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, push-notification, rss, ios9

I'm building an application that is showing a website with a WebView. On this website are from time to time some news with an RSS feed.
Is it possible to send push notifications to the users of the application whenever a new article appears? If yes: How would it work with swift?

Thank you for your help and have a nice day ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A push notification just cannot be generated from a website. If you have a backend server from which you are getting some data, your backend server can generate the push when a new article is served in that website. So your backend server needs to listen to the RSS feeds as well..
Here is a [link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1) for an elegant push notification tutorial.
Hope this helps you.